# How callbacks work with $scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Imagine we have an external module has a function that needs a callback parameter for a `async` task. As our parameter is a function, and they call that callback function in their module, so how do we use `$scope` that is out of our digest cycle? How `angularjs` handles such things?

And also we use `$scope.apply()` or `$scope.digest()` in such situations, so how do they work?

**Note:** I don't need you to provide some codes necessarily, just want to know about concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
externalModule.doSomething(param, function(result) {
  $scope.result = result;
  $scope.$apply();
})
```

That's it actually. However it is good style to wrap all external modules - as an example you can look at $http, $interval, $timeout wraping calls to javascript functions.
So you should put this code in some factory externalModuleWrap:

```
module.factory('externalModuleWrap', function($rootScope, $q) {
  return {
    doSomething: function(param) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      externalModule.doSomething(param, function(result) { defer.resolve(result); }
      $rootScope.$apply();
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
})
```

Now you can call externalModuleWrap from any point of your angular project, without problems.